# Formula for running balance for first of month

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet that is importing a .csv.  I'd like to figure out a formula that will figure out what the running balance is for the first of the month (for any specific month of my choosing).  This would be based off of my sheet in the attached image.

So for example, if I wanted to pull the running balance of the beginning of March, the result should be $50,000.  This formula would be run on a separate sheet where I'll be pulling a yearly balance sheet that tells me what the beginning balance is for each month.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a second tab and place Start Date and End Date in cells A1 and B1, then place the dates to search between in cells A2 and B2.  In cell C1 place this formula:

```
=iferror(query(Sheet1!A1:B, " Select A,B where A >= date '"&TEXT(B1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and A <= date '"&TEXT(B2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'  order by A", 1))
```

You may need to Format your Date cells as Date.